# Remove old numbers with VCF file

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

So I have a VCARD that I have been testing with

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Smith;John;;;
FN:John Smith
TEL;CELL:+61000000000
TEL;CELL:+61000000001
TEL;CELL:+61000000002
END:VCARD
```

The vcard imports correctly after being sent to the phone, and I can see all three numbers appear under the Mobile Menu, however if one of the numbers change, how can I remove the old number using the VCF file? I've tried

1. Changing the number in the VCF and importing it again, however this left the old number and added the new one, which makes sense
2. I tried importing the VCF with the number removed this did not work.

I have read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard however, there does not seem to be a prefix or suffix I can issue to remove that particular number from a contact.

Is there another way I can remove old numbers from a contact card already on a phone by run a file such as a vcf?

The problem I am trying to solve,

People I work with can have up to four different sim cards depending on geo location, these numbers for some places can expire every six months.

I need a way to export an update of changes to both Android and Apple phones.

I am open to all suggestions, if you have a way I can email a file to users and have them import the changes on their phone I would be very grateful .

Answer (score 0):

According to the VCard RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-5.5), you can set a UID to the VCard itself to be identified in general. For each phone number you could add a PID (property ID), so this number can be matched as same entity. In theory, it should be possible to exchange the number. But i don't know, if this works in your VCard implementations.

Unfortunately, a delete mechanism is not provided...